# How to delete the entire row in the csv file in ruby 1.9.2

Tags: ruby, csv

I am building an app which reads the data from the CSV file and stores those data into the database. I csv file which I get from the 3rd party consists of header in the first row which has to be deleted before pushing those data in to the database. How do I delete the first row pro grammatically and then push only the values or data to the database.I am using ruby 1.9.2 version, so I dont have to use "fastercsv". I am using the standard CSV library.

Kindly help me out

Comment: Why dont you just skip the first row?

Comment: @Hck How do I skip the first row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can fetch all the rows at once by using:

```
arr_of_arrs = CSV.read("path/to/file.csv")
```

And then you can use `arr_of_arrs.drop(1)` to remove header.
Or you can use `arr_of_arrs.each_with_index` to skip the first row (header), like this:

```
arr_of_arrs.each_with_index do |e, i|
  next if i == 0

  #process each row here
end
```

Comment: Fetching all rows into memory is not always good. The CSVs I have are atleast 400mb in size.

Answer (score 8):

when you do:

```
CSV.open(filename, :headers => true) do |row|
  # it will use the first line as headers. now you can do:
  row['my_header_value']
end
```